# Wifi direct - NetworkInfo deprecated

Tags: android, wifi-direct, wifip2p

When one follows the guide for implementing WiFi direct from google doc [here](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct) you need to use `NetworkInfo` .

The document is last updated: `Last updated 2022-10-14 UTC`.

```
NetworkInfo networkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
```

Currently [NetworkInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo) is deprecated.

Does anyone know any way to get another object from intent which is not deprecated and it does same logic?

Or it's just google behaving like google

Also in `WifiP2pManager` they added a new method for api 33: [addExternalApprover](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager#addExternalApprover(android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.Channel,%20android.net.MacAddress,%20android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.ExternalApproverRequestListener)),
if anyone knows where it fits in the feature implementation, any hint is appreciated